# black boxes instead of Greek letter Delta

Tags: article

I am using `jotart` class (journal of operator theory). Everything is fine but in the output instead of `\Delta` there is a black box. All other Greek letters appear correctly. In the same `.tex` file if I use amsart class then `\Delta` appears correctly.

Comment: It is hard to judge what goes wrong if you do not provide us a MWE (minimal working example). So please give us some more detailed information and a code snippet we can copy/paste and figure it out ourselfs.

Comment: thank you working on a MWE I sort it out it was because of  ''' \usepackage{breqn}'''

Comment: is there any other way to replace \dmath as I cannot use \usepackage{breqn}.

Comment: Use `amsmath`  `align` and add line breaks by hand (I would want to do that in a published journl article in any case)

Comment: Thank you. I used split and it works fine.